# editor account in wordpress for content

Tags: page-specific-settings

Is that possible we can give client editor account for the user in admin dashboard without all the functionality? In which client can only change content not moreover that. 
I appreciate it if someone helps me through this guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily using a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/